# Como fazer uma consulta para saber a médias de pessoas por dia de uma semana

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, oracle, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá, gostaria de saber como fazer uma consulta(Query) no banco de dados Oracle para saber: Qual a quantidade média de hospedes por dia de uma de semana qualquer.
Segue abaixo o script do banco:

```
CREATE TABLE APP.HOSPEDAGENS (  
      hsp_id number(6),  
      hsp_checkin Date, 
      hsp_preco_total number(8,2),  
      hsp_checkout Date,  
      hsp_cli_id number(6),  
      hsp_qua_id number(6),  
      CONSTRAINT pk_hsp_id  PRIMARY KEY(hsp_id)  );  
ALTER TABLE APP.HOSPEDAGENS ADD FOREIGN KEY (hsp_cli_id) REFERENCES APP.CLIENTES (cli_id);  
ALTER TABLE APP.HOSPEDAGENS ADD FOREIGN KEY (hsp_qua_id) REFERENCES APP.QUARTOS (qua_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível retornar o dia da semana usando a função to_char, [formatando a data](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780) com o parâmetro 'd', que retorna o dia da semana. Assim é possível agrupar a consulta pelo dia da semana e realizar a contagem, ex:

```
select to_char(hsp_checkin, 'd') as DIA_DA_SEMANA, 
       count(*) as total 
  from HOSPEDAGENS 
 group by to_char(hsp_checkin, 'd')
 order by 1
```

Comment: Exemplo no sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff2030/1/0